# Swift Multipeer Connectivity Cannot Connect Using Bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I am currently building an app which uses MPC (Multipeer Connectivity Framework) to send and receive data between two devices. I learnt MPC from this article [Building a Chat App in Swift Using Multipeer Connectivity Framework](http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/)
. It works very well with wifi (local network), but failed with bluetooth.

Browsing and advertising is good. I can see the other device and I can send invitation to ask it to join the chat as shown in the article. And the other device can receive the notification. When I taped the accept button, the two devices changed to connecting state, but after a few seconds the connection failed. I got the message "Did not connect to session".

```
func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state{
    case MCSessionState.Connected:
        print("Connected to session: \(session)")

    case MCSessionState.Connecting:
        print("Connecting to session: \(session)")

    default:
        print("Did not connect to session: \(session)")
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether this has something to do with bluetooth speed. I noticed that when I use bluetooth, seeing other devices and inviting other devices are very slow.  I don't know how long the connecting state will last before it fails.

Comment: hi @jingplusplus have you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Arpit, Not yet solved...  Let me know if you ever successfully connected with Bluetooth, I have no clues why it doesn't work.